# Can I put impose a time limit on JavaScript (e.g., using an iframe)?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'd like to run some external JavaScript with a time restriction, so that if it takes more than N seconds it will be stopped.

Some browsers, e.g. Firefox, already do this with a dialog that asks if you want to allow a script to keep running. However, I'm looking for a bit more:

- I want to set my own time limit rather than use the browser's default (e.g., I believe Chrome's is much longer than Firefox's).
- I want to be able to do this on a per-script basis, not per-page. One page may contain multiple scripts that I want to restrict in this way (hence my idea to use `<iframe>` elements).

I was thinking it would be very convenient if there were simply an attribute I could attach to an `<iframe>`—e.g., something like `js-time-limit="5000"` (I just made that up)—but I haven't been able to find anything like that.

Is this possible? To put a configurable time limit on JavaScript execution in a browser?

Comment: why dont you add the iframe dynamically after the page has loaded?

Comment: what you mean by time limit? To disappear after 5 seconds? to appear after 5 seconds? To launch a nuclear misil after 5 seconds? I think you should explain yourself better

Comment: @stackErr: Before or after, if it has bad JavaScript in it (e.g., an infinite loop) it's going to lock up the browser once I add it. I want to basically say, "You have X seconds to run all your JavaScript; after that, just turn JavaScript off."

Comment: If the iframe is doing computation work and doesn't need to access the DOM, then use web workers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

Comment: @JoeFrambach: That seems like a good idea. Care to provide that as an answer?

Comment: It doesn't answer the question. In fact I'm thinking about marking the question as closed: "It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form."

Comment: @JoeFrambach: I guess I committed the sin of asking about an implementation rather than intent. You pointed me in a smarter direction, which was helpful. I could imagine others searching for similar info on Google, finding this question, and benefiting from being reminded of web workers.

Comment: @JoeFrambach: That said, I can update the question to be more general if you like. Alternately, if you just want to close it, obviously I can't stop you.

Comment: You should update the question.

Comment: I updated the question to ask more generally about imposing a time limit on JavaScript execution. I left 'iframe' in the title of the question because I suspect others might have a similar problem and (like me) think too narrowly, assuming an `<iframe>`-based solution must be the answer. This way, this question should turn up in their search.

Comment: Here's a library that can abstract away the hard parts for you! http://adambom.github.io/parallel.js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the iframe is doing computation work and doesn't need to access the DOM, then use web workers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers

Here is also a library that can abstract away the hard parts for you! http://adambom.github.io/parallel.js

Important parts:

> Dedicated Web Workers provide a simple means for web content to run scripts in background threads.

> If you need to immediately terminate a running worker, you can do so by calling the worker's terminate() method: `myWorker.terminate();`

**Browser compatibility**

```
Chrome  Firefox (Gecko)  Internet Explorer  Opera  Safari (WebKit)
   3        3.5 (1.9.1)          10         10.60        4
```

Answer (score 0):

For posterity: my original goal was to allow users of a website to submit JS code and run it in the background with a time limit so that, e.g., infinite loops don't wreak havoc on the CPU.

I created a library called [Lemming.js](https://t.co/JTdM67p3BL) using the approach [Joe suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17238897/105570). You use it like this:

```
var lemming = new Lemming('code to eval');

lemming.onTimeout(function() {
  alert('Timed out!');
});

lemming.onResult(function(result) {
  alert('Result: ' + result);
});

lemming.run({ timeout: 5000 });
```

You can [check out the GitHub repo](https://github.com/dtao/lemming.js) for more details.